# pipe bad file descriptor error

Tags: c, pipe

Ok. So I am trying to make a program that will create 3 processess: A,B and C. And I want the messages to travel like this:

std.input -> (A-> B -> C -> A) -> std.output

Now the problem is when I run this program I get:

> ERROR: Error in process B: close(pipeB[1]) 3 4
>    (9; Bad file descriptor)

Funny thing is that if I comment out the previous line, which is:

```
if(close(pipeB[0] == -1))       syserr("Error in process B: %s\n", "close(pipeB[0])")
```

I get no error messages after running the program.

```
char message[] = "Hello from process A!\n";
int buffA_len;
char buffA [BUF_SIZE];

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pipeA[2];
    int pipeC[2];

if(pipe(pipeA) == -1)                       syserr("Error in pipeA\n");
if(pipe(pipeC) == -1)                       syserr("Error in pipeC\n");
    switch(fork()){
        case -1:
            syserr("Error in first fork()\n");
        case 0: ;
            int buffA_rec_len;
            int a = pipeA[1];
            int b = pipeA[0];
            if(close (pipeA[1]) == -1)      syserr("Error in process B: %s\n", "close(pipeA[1])");
            if(close (0)        == -1)      syserr("Error in process B: %s\n", "close(0)");
            if(dup   (pipeA[0]) == -1)      syserr("Error in process B: %s\n", "dup(pipeA[0])");
            if(close (pipeA[0]) == -1)      syserr("Error in process B: %s\n", "close(pipeA[0])");


        int pipeB[2];
        if(pipe(pipeB) == -1)           syserr("Error in pipeB\n");

        switch(fork()){
            case -1:
                syserr("Error in second fork()\n");
            case 0:

                if(close (pipeB[1]) == -1)      syserr("Error in process C: %s\n", "close(pipeB[1])");
                if(close (0) == -1)             syserr("Error in process C: %s\n", "close(0)");
                if(dup(pipeB[0]) == -1)         syserr("Error in process C: %s\n", "dup(pipeB[0])");
                if(close (pipeB[0]) == -1)      syserr("Error in process C: %s\n", "close(pipeB[0])");

                if(close(pipeC[0]) == -1)       syserr("Error in process C: %s\n", "close(pipeC[0])");
                if(close (1)   == -1)           syserr("Error in process C: %s\n", "close(1)");
                if(dup(pipeC[1]) == -1)         syserr("Error in process C: %s\n", "dup(pipeC[1])");
                if(close (pipeC[1]) == -1)      syserr("Error in process C: %s\n", "close(pipeC[1])");
                exit(0);
            default:
                if(close (1)   == -1)           syserr("Error in process B: %s\n", "close(1)");
                if(dup(pipeB[1]) == -1)         syserr("Error in process B: %s\n", "dup(pipeB[1])");

/*Here are those lines!*/

                int b0 = pipeB[0];
                int b1 = pipeB[1];
                if(close(pipeB[0] == -1))       syserr("Error in process B: %s\n", "close(pipeB[0])");
                if(close(pipeB[1] == -1))       syserr("Error in process B: %s %d %d\n", "close(pipeB[1])",b0,b1);


                if(close(pipeC[0]) == -1)       syserr("Error in process B: %s\n", "close(pipeC[0])");
                if(close(pipeC[1]) == -1)       syserr("Error in process B: %s\n", "close(pipeC[1])");
                exit(0);
        }


        exit(0);
    default:
        if(close(pipeA[0]) == -1)   syserr("Error in process A: %s\n", "close(pipeA[0])");
        if(close(pipeC[1]) == -1)   syserr("Error in process A: %s\n", "close(pipeC[1])");


}
```

}

Any ideas why?

Comment: Perhaps add some debug code to emit the contents of your pipe variables and the results of your `dup()` calls?

Comment: @AndrewHenie I;ve added the code to print the values of pipeB[0] and pipeB[1]

Comment: So what's closing file descriptor 4?  Assuming Linux, can you run your code under `strace` to see what's going on?  `strace -f -o /path/to/output/file command` should work.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used strace. What exactly should i type in 'command'? I'm using ubuntu 15.04

Comment: The man page is here:  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html  And here are some usage examples:  http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/11/strace-examples/  The `-f` option causes `strace` to also trace child processes after a `fork()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lines are trying to close whatever the `int` value of  `pipeB[0] == -1` is:

```
if(close(pipeB[0] == -1))       syserr("Error in process B: %s\n", "close(pipeB[0])");
if(close(pipeB[1] == -1))       syserr("Error in process B: %s %d %d\n", "close(pipeB[1])",b0,b1);
```

You are actually looking for:

```
if(close(pipeB[0]) == -1)       syserr("Error in process B: %s\n", "close(pipeB[0])");
if(close(pipeB[1]) == -1)       syserr("Error in process B: %s %d %d\n", "close(pipeB[1])",b0,b1);
```

Note how the comparison is outside the `close` call arguments.

Comment: Hah! You are right! I spent like 2 hours trying to find such a basic mistake! Thanks!

Comment: And some people wonder why I never do any operations like `open()` or `close()` inside a conditional expression.